# Chrome and Safari handling htaccess SSL redirects differently

Tags: .htaccess, google-chrome, mod-rewrite, ssl, safari

I'm a bit out of my depth here so sorry if my understanding is wrong. Hopefully you can help.

My website should use SSL throughout the whole site. The domain I want to use is https://example.com

Here's what happens when I visit different combinations:

- `https://example.com` --> It works great
- `http://example.com` --> It redirects to `https://example.com`
- `http://www.example.com` --> **In Safari, I get a certificate warning**. In Chrome, I get redirected to `https://example.com` correctly.
- `https://www.example.com` --> **In both Chrome and Safari**, I get a certificate warning.

Is there any clean way around the bottom two situations, and why do Chrome and Safari handle it differently?

Relevant parts of .htaccess (this is taken from https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs-apache/blob/master/.htaccess):

```
# ##############################################################################
# # URL REWRITES                                                               #
# ##############################################################################

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# | Rewrite engine                                                             |
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Turn on the rewrite engine and enable the `FollowSymLinks` option (this is
# necessary in order for the following directives to work).

# If your web host doesn't allow the `FollowSymlinks` option, you may need to
# comment it out and use `Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch`, but be aware of the
# performance impact.
# http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/misc/perf-tuning.html#symlinks

# Also, some cloud hosting services require `RewriteBase` to be set.
# http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/frequently-asked-question/why-is-mod-rewrite-not-working-on-my-site

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
  # Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    RewriteEngine On
  # RewriteBase /
</IfModule>

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# | Suppressing / Forcing the `www.` at the beginning of URLs                  |
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# The same content should never be available under two different URLs,
# especially not with and without `www.` at the beginning. This can cause
# SEO problems (duplicate content), and therefore, you should choose one
# of the alternatives and redirect the other one.

# By default `Option 1` (no `www.`) is activated.
# http://no-www.org/faq.php?q=class_b

# If you would prefer to use `Option 2`, just comment out all the lines
# from `Option 1` and uncomment the ones from `Option 2`.

# IMPORTANT: NEVER USE BOTH RULES AT THE SAME TIME!

# - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

# Option 1: rewrite www.example.com → example.com

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

# - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

# Option 2: rewrite example.com → www.example.com

# Be aware that the following might not be a good idea if you use "real"
# subdomains for certain parts of your website.

# <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
#    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
#    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
#    RewriteCond %{SERVER_ADDR} !=127.0.0.1
#    RewriteCond %{SERVER_ADDR} !=::1
#    RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
# </IfModule>

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# | Secure Sockets Layer (SSL)                                                 |
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Rewrite secure requests properly in order to prevent SSL certificate warnings.
# E.g.: prevent `https://www.example.com` when your certificate only allows
# `https://secure.example.com`.

 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443
    RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
 </IfModule>

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# | HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS)                                      |
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Force client-side SSL redirection.

# If a user types `example.com` in his browser, the above rule will redirect
# him to the secure version of the site. That still leaves a window of
# opportunity (the initial HTTP connection) for an attacker to downgrade or
# redirect the request.

# The following header ensures that browser will ONLY connect to your server
# via HTTPS, regardless of what the users type in the address bar.

# http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-websec-strict-transport-sec-14#section-6.1
# http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/transport-layer-security/

# IMPORTANT: Remove the `includeSubDomains` optional directive if the subdomains
# are not using HTTPS.

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
   Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=16070400; includeSubDomains"
</IfModule>
```

Comment: What's your .htaccess structure?

Comment: Also, what was the URL given when registering the SSL certificate, did it include the www. or not?

Comment: @BigChris I have posted the relevant parts of the htaccess. It looks huge but mostly it's just comments, I got it from the HTML5 boilerplate. The URL registered was example.com - no WWW. Ideally I want HTTP OR HTTPS with a WWW to be redirected to https://example.com before the certificate is invoked - but I'm not sure if this is possible.

Comment: I think your rewrite condition from www.example.com to example.com (`RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on`) is causing the redirect to example.com to not fire. The statement says to run the RewriteRule if HTTPS not equal to "on" (i.e. "off"). Your very last test (`https://www.example.com`) has HTTPS on so it doesn't meet the conditions to fire the redirect... or I've got it completely wrong, for which I apologise!